# Regarding typedefing structs

Tags: c++, struct

Please go easy on me as I'm walking a thin line here. I really searched the existing threads and I could only see statements with no examples and it just went over my head. I have been thinking whether or not to ask this for two days because I'm frankly scared to ask a silly question here. But I think I'll take the risk now and hope you go easy on me as this is my first question.

Those existent threads suggested that `typedef`ing struct will save repeating codes, but how? Any example please? I have the following for instance:

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* value;
};
```

To create a new node, I would say:

```
Node n1;
```

Even if I typedef the struct like:

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* value;
} type;
```

To create a new node, I would do:

```
type n2;
```

I don't really see much difference. Please provide some example that really showcases the usefulness of typedef on structs.

Comment: If you reference other questions you should include links to them, they're probably questions about C, not C++.

Comment: It's not required at all in C++?

Comment: Not in the example you have given, no. `class` / `struct` definitions in c++ already introduce new types and don't need to be `typedef`ed.

Answer (score 1):

For that sort of thing, a typedef is useful in C - in C++ not so much. In C, you can't just type `Node` when you have a `struct Node` - you have to actually type `struct Node`. So a typedef can save some typing there.

In C++ it's more useful when dealing with templated types. For example

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::pair<int, std::string>> MyMap;
```

This lets you use e.g. `MyMap::iterator` instead of `std::map<std::string, std::pair<int, std::string>>::iterator`, which is a lot easier to type.

Comment: Wow, I have no clue what map is. :(